# Include in SELECT a column that isn't actually in the database

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to execute a SELECT statement that includes a column of a static string value.  I've done this in Access, but never with raw SQL.  Is this possible?

Example:

```
 Name  | Status
 ------+--------
 John  | Unpaid
 Terry | Unpaid
 Joe   | Unpaid
```

In the above example, the "Status" column doesn't exist in the database.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You may want to use:

```
SELECT Name, 'Unpaid' AS Status FROM table;
```

---

The `SELECT` clause syntax, as defined in [MSDN: SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx), is as follows:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
[ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES ] ] 
<select_list>
```

Where the `expression` can be a **constant**, function, any combination of column names, constants, and functions connected by an operator or operators, or a subquery.

Comment: You actually want  (in this case)  'Unpaid' AS Status

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, that would be a better example in fact. Fixed answer.

Comment: Ah, an alias with a static value... that makes so much sense after the fact of course.  Thanks so much.  :)