# Adding A Column that doesn't exist in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I want to add a column in a query that does not exist in a table and return it as a result. So lets say TABLE_TEST has column A, B and I want to return values for A, B and C. I am trying to do

```
SELECT A, B, C=3 FROM TABLE_TEST
```

or

```
SELECT *, C=3 FROM TABLE_TEST
```

Can this be done in MySQL, Postgresel or MSSQL?

Comment: Further to the answers below: If you need a string instead of an integer, you need single quotes around it. (That is, while `select 3 as c from table` works, `select dummy as c from table` or `select "dummy" as c from table` try to look for a column already named `dummy`, so you need `select 'dummy' as c from table`. Might vary with your SQL engine. Via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504163/include-in-select-a-column-that-isnt-actually-in-the-database and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185743/how-can-i-create-a-blank-hardcoded-column-in-a-sql-query

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
select a, b, 3 as c from table_test
```

That's it. It works on three db engines you've mentioned.

Comment: You could also do _3 as "My Fake Column"_ if you want to incorporate spaces in the column name.

Answer (score 11):

You should use:

```
SELECT A,B, 3 AS C FROM TABLE_TEST
```

Comment: You are missing a comma after B, which makes the query invalid.

Answer (score 3):

you can use as

```
Select a,b, 3 as c from table
```

This is known as `alias`