# Dummy Field with Values in addition to selecting fields from table

Tags: sql

I want to add a dummy field with values in addition to selecting fields from my data source?

Comment: `select 'dummy text' as dummycol1, 123 as dummycol2, col1, col2, ... from tablename`.

Comment: Note, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504163/include-in-select-a-column-that-isnt-actually-in-the-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include in SELECT a column that isn't actually in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504163/include-in-select-a-column-that-isnt-actually-in-the-database)